# Can't make a connection to LDAP with ldap2dns

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, openldap

I'm trying to connect with ldap2dns:

[test2dns on github](https://github.com/bklang/ldap2dns)

[test2dns on lunchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ldap2dns)

But i'm just getting: "Warning - Could not connect to any LDAP server"

```
user@ldap:~$ ldap2dns -D  ou=DNS,dc=test,dc=com -o db -h localhost
Warning - Could not connect to any LDAP server
```

Anything else with ldap works (Like ldapsearch and other ldap utils).

(Running ubuntu server 14.04, openldap)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, It was a version issue.

(After some networking sniffing one has figure it out)

can be fixed with `allow_ldap2.ldif`:

`dn: cn=config
add: olcAllows
olcAllows: bind_v2`

Then run:

`ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f ./allow_ldap2.ldif`